# How are requests handled when we use opencv with django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, opencv, django-views

I am trying to make a Face detection and facial recognition system using Django so, I used OpenCV to handle recognition but I am a bit confused about how the request is handled when we make a request, in  **views.py** for each request does it generate a new OpenCV thread.

```
def index(request):
        .....
        .....

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while(True):
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            # Our operations on the frame come here
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Display the resulting frame
            cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        # When everything done, release the capture
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        ...........
        .........
```

and if my application is deployed somewhere and a user makes a request, does he able to use this.
*what will happen if a user makes a request when the Django application is deployed somewhere ?*

Comment: Your input from user is in video format ?

Comment: @ZdaR no it will be a photo but yes I want to know about video too

Comment: If it is a photo then you do not need `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and `while True` stuff. Simply get the image using `cv2.imdecode()` and all the processing you want to do on top of it.

Comment: @ZdaR ok but the question is different is about request and deployment

Comment: Needed extra info of how you run Django.

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 I am just asking if I used OpenCV and deploy my application somewhere and a host opens it, will he able to use it as no dependency for OpenCV are install in the host computer and if yes how requests and handle in Django for opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do face recognition on Django server, that code won't work. This VideoCapture is executed on Django machine, not user computer.

User has to use some front-end app which use installed OpenCV, or other method to capture frame eg. Media Devices API + webpage, then POST this frame to Django app on server where it's processing further.